# jQuery submit handler for form with single input field doesn't trigger on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a form with an input element but no submit button. I use jQuery to attach an onsubmit handler:

```
$('#tickerbox-form').submit(function (ev) {
    alert('submit'); // I have other code that actually does something...
    return false;
});
```

I want the (anonymous function) handler to be invoked when the Enter button is pressed in the input field. This works for me on Safari, but not on IE. What am I doing wrong?

btw: IE does act on the Enter, and invokes a POST request on the URL for the specified "action" parameter of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to capture the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key instead:

```
$('#tickerbox-form').keypress(function(e){
  if (e.which==13){
    $(this).submit();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like IE doesn't submit forms on enter by default.  Read [here](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/submit-a-form-in-ie-with-enter):

Comment: Excellent info in the supplied link -- that explained the problem for me and I could devise a solution -- Thx!

Answer (score 0):

On IE it will work only if you have a single input field ie in your case only **tickerbox-form**

Even the definition of the command at jquery states this.

> "Depending on the browser, the Enter
>   key may only cause a form submission
>   if the form has exactly one text
>   field, or only when there is a submit
>   button present. The interface should
>   not rely on a particular behavior for
>   this key unless the issue is forced by
>   observing the keypress event for
>   presses of the Enter key."

For your purpose if you have more fields use something like adding an attribute **ontextchange** or like:

```
$('#tickerbox-form').keydown(function (ev) {
    alert('submit'); // Check here if enter is pressed
    return false;
});
```